# Convert to Image Object from OpenReadCompletedEventArgs Result

Tags: c#, web-services, windows-phone-7, png, media

I'm busy with a windows phone application that calls a webservice that in turn returns a png image. In my code where I handle the returned result it looks like this:

```
void ImgDownloader_OpenReadCompleted(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    var graphImage = e.Result;
    imgGraph.Source = graphImage; //Error here

    //Stop loading animation
    refreshProgressBar.IsIndeterminate = false;
}
```

But currently I'm getting an error (See comment) that says:

> Cannot implicitly convert type IO.Stream to Media.ImageSource.

Would a normal type parse work here or should this be handled in another way?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You should use the [`BitmapImage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) class:

```
void ImgDownloader_OpenReadCompleted(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    var graphImage = e.Result;

    BitmapImage bitmap = new BitmapImage();
    bitmap.SetSource(graphImage);
    imgGraph.Source = bitmap;

    //Stop loading animation
    refreshProgressBar.IsIndeterminate = false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I've tried the code above but I'm getting an 'Unspecified Error' on the 'bitmap.SetSource()' method. This can't be good...

Comment: Maybe you should try to reset the stream to beginning by adding `graphImage.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);`